# Prove game Hex must have a winner

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

About 7 years ago I was asked this question. I remembered it right now, and I can't solve it.

Prove that no matter how you play, the [game Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)) will have a winner at the end.

Comment: Please define Hex. Preferably in the question, but at least in a link

Comment: The wiki link is added. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really nice proof given [here](https://web.mit.edu/sp.268/www/hex-notes.pdf).

*Summary:* After a game is completed, define the graph $G=(V,E)$, where $V$ is the set of vertices of the hexagons, and $E$ consists of only the edges which are between adjacent hexagons claimed by opposite players. Each internal vertex will have degree $0$ or $2$, according to whether it is surrounded by all hexagons belonging to the same player, or a mix of two of one player and one of the other. Therefore, the graph decomposes into a disjoint union of paths and cycles. You can then show that there must be two paths connecting the four corners of the board into tow pairs; each of these paths will trace out a winning chain of hexagons. Please refer to the linked document for the details.

Comment: This nice proof is due to David Gale in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1979.11994922).